# AngularJS 1.2 support: Security patches and existing vulnerabilities

Tags: angularjs, security

[AngularJS support page](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status) states that AngularJS 1.2 should still receive security patches.

On the other hand, it seems that the latest 1.2 version ([1.2.32](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular/v/1.2.32)) is still impacted by a few high vulnerabilities.

[snyk.io](https://snyk.io/test/npm/angular/1.2.32) shows 4 high vulnerabilities and 11 medium.

What are the criteria for a vulnerability to be fixed? Should AngularJS 1.2 still be considered as safe for production (until 2021 at least)?